# Database query different results

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've encountered a new problem while editing my Magento store. This problem is PHP & MySQL related and not neccessary related to Magento because I tried using raw PHP code that dealt with the database, and not Magento handlers and helpers.

```
$a = "Tapet colectia Alice Whow C";

$sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
  WHERE `value` LIKE '%".$a."%'
  LIMIT 0, 30
";
```

When I search for the `$a` variable I'm getting 0 results, but when I search for the variable's value `Tapet colectia Alice Whow C`, I get the desired results.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Have you tried printing the query and run it directly to mysql?

Comment: Being a newbie,its hard to know you know that from, i didnt paste any code containing mysql_functions. Anyway, i'll put an eye on prepared statements today. You're sure the problem comes from there? Cause i used magento's connectivity handlers and i get the same results ( zero ) when im searching for expressions like that.
@JA: Yes,i ran it from phpmyadmin and it gave me the right results. The problem appears when im using the variable instead of the expression,in the php files.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai: Then you got your answer. Problem lies in your php code what you haven't provided here.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai: BTW, were you using back-ticks or single quotation in your original query?

Comment: The code is copied straight from the file. It is as you see it. I tried removing the quotes and dots around the variable in <code>$sql</code> but its like the same thing.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary There's no tax on the word "please". There should however be a tax on each additional superfluous exclamation mark.

Comment: @DanCapitanDePlai No your problem doesn't come from there, it was just something to point out.

Comment: @DaveRandom Thank you :) Will mind it in future.

Comment: `$num = mysql_numrows($result); echo $num;` should be `$num = mysql_num_rows($result); echo $num;` in your code.

Comment: Please insert a `var_dump($sql);` line right before your `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Nu merge');` line and post the dump.

Comment: Now that's embarassing : it was a white-space character in plus. Im sorry for such mess and i thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So you're making calls to a Magento database, huh? Well, here's how I usually do it:

```
require_once '/path/to/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$a = 'Tapet colectia Alice Whow C';
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('catalog_product_entity_varchar')
             ->where($db->quoteIdentifier('value') . ' LIKE ?', "%{$a}%");
$result = $db->fetchAll($select);
echo count($result);
```

Comment: BTW, this is using [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) (included in Magento) if you'd like to learn more about the syntax of the `select()` statement.

Comment: Yeah, the mysql stuff should be abandoned and using bound values is more secure, but look at the complexity that gets introduced in moving to an OOP model.  Might as well be writing a novel in Java... ugh.

Comment: It doesnt solve my problem,but it's still useful. The error persists only for that expression ( so far,i didnt test'em all ),and i think i can make a 'patch' for it and get the desired results in other manner.